# Django: Mostrar posts que contengan la categoría dada

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Soy nuevo en Django. Estoy utilizando las vistas basadas en clases. Necesito retornar en la vista 'CategoryDetailView', todos los posts que contengan esta categoría. Pero no logro resolverlo.

En modelo de Post, relaciono la categoría con el post en el atributo 'categories':

```
"""Posts models."""

# Django
from django.db import models

from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from categories.models import Category

class Post(models.Model):
    """Post model."""
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    profile = models.ForeignKey('users.Profile', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image_header = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/photos')
    post = RichTextField()

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_draft = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title',)


    def __str__(self):
        """Return title and username."""
        return '{} by @{}'.format(self.title, self.user.username)



    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

En el modelo de categorías como tal, solo manejo los atributos de nombre y url:

```
"""Categories"""

from django.db import models

from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField


# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    """Category model."""
    

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

En esta vista es donde intento mostrar todos los posts que contengan la categoría dada mediante la URL y hacer la validación:

```
"""Categories views"""

# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Models
from categories.models import Category
from posts.models import Post

class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    """Detail post."""
    template_name = 'categories/category.html'
    model = Category
    context_object_name = 'category'
    slug_field = 'url'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'url'


    def get_queryset(self):
        return Category.objects.all()
   
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['posts'] = Post.objects.all()

        return context
```

Finalmente, tengo el archivo de urls.py en donde recibo por parametro el nombre de la categoría dada. Acá lo tengo como 'slug':

```
"""Categories urls"""

from django.urls import path
from categories import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        route='',
        view=views.CategoryDetailView.as_view(),
        name='category'
    ),
    path(
        route='category/<slug:url>/',
        view=views.CategoryDetailView.as_view(),
        name='detail'
    ),
]
```

Comment: En `get_queryset` regresas objetos `Category` deberías cambiarlo por `Post`.

Comment: Al parecer no. Si hago ese cambio, obtengo 'No post found matching the query'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deberias de reestructurar la view, esto debido a que estas utilizando una misma view para dos procesos diferentes, o podes utilizar re_path en la url y utilizar una sola.

```
def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
    parametro = self.kwargs['url']
    if parametro:
        return Post.objects.filter(categories_in=parametro)
    return Post.objects.all()
```

de esta forma no necesitaría el get_context_data, también deberías de cambiar el context_object_name = 'post'